# Synchronous call in angular 8

Tags: angular

I need to set value of this.todo so that it can be send to child component as @Input() property.

But the code is getting executed first and API response is coming later and I am getting undefined error.

I have tried to make an synchronous request as below

1) Using promises
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sync-promise

```
private async fetchData(){

    const promise = this.httpClient.get(this.url).toPromise();
    promise.then((data)=>{
      this.todo = data;
      console.log("Promise resolved with: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log("Promise rejected with " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  }
```

2) using async and await
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sync-async-and-await

```
async fetchData(){
    const data = await this.httpClient.get(this.url).toPromise();
    this.todo = data;
    console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data)); 
  }
```

but both are failing.

So, my question is,

1) How can I make synchronous call in angular.

2) Is this a right way of doing, please suggest as I am a new be to angular.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you not Initialise `this.todo` with a default value and then update it as part of the async callback?

Comment: It would be really help to know how they are failing.

Comment: @fredrik, I have added two examples of stackblitz, please check their console window.

Comment: I am not going to run those to see the error message. You should include them in the question itself. As the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page states, such information should be given in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need the call to be synchronous, and personally that's something I would probably avoid.

The reason you're getting the console error is because you're trying to access a property on an object that hasn't been initialised yet.

```
template: `<h1>Todo: {{todo.title}}</h1>`
```

When todo is `null` or `undefined` there is no title property.

There are a few ways you could go about fixing this but the simplest way would be to check that to todo is initialised before trying to access the title property. Fortunately TypeScript has something known as a "existential operator" or "safe navigation operator" which does this for us and is as simple as changing your template to the following

```
template: `<h1>Todo: {{todo?.title}}</h1>`
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Darren, you solution resolved the error, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At first I need to refer to @Darren Lamb answer since it mentions the problem at make it clear. I just want to add a possible solution.

TL;DR: Embrace asyncronous calls and work with, not against, Observables.

One way I like to handle problems like the one you are mentioning is to render the `ChildComponent` only once its inputs have been returned by the API. Something like the following:

```
<child-selector *ngIf="childInput$ | async as input" [attribute]="input">
</child-selector>
```

This should make sure that your value is available when you actually use it.

Comment: sorry for the late reply @chund, your solution solves the problem, but it makes multiple request to the server.
here is an example
https://netbasal.com/angular-stop-using-observable-when-you-should-use-a-promise-8da0788a8d2

Comment: Hi, yes if you use the selector multiple times that would be correct. In that case my solution is definetly not to be preferred